# Adding external .js files to a new Rails 6 web app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have created a new rails 6 app. in rails 6, javascript folder is outside assets. I have copied all the `css` and `js` files from an existing application to this new one and `application.css`,`application.js` are updated. `application.css` working fine but `application.js` is not working. while compiling(`bin/webpack`) webpack it is showing error like this =>

> ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/application.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'file_name' in >'/home/app/javascript/packs'
>   @ ./app/javascript/packs/application.js.

in `application.js` i have added those `.js` files with `require('file_name')` syntax. and i pasted all the `.js` files on `app/javascript/packs` folder. please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `app/javascript/packs` folder is special with Webpacker. It should only have the javascript files that "boot up" your page. This would typically be `application.js` if you were loading everything from a single script, but you could also have something like `calendar.js` if you had a special calendar page/widget.

All other code would typically be in the `app/javascript/src` folder. In your `app/javascript/packs/application.js` file, you could then `require('src/file_name')` to require the file at `app/javascript/src/file_name.js`

Comment: i have created `src` folder inside `app/javascript` folder and pasted all .js files into it. application.js also done on the same way you mentioned above. still compiler showing the same error.

Comment: In config/webpacker.yaml, what are your values for source_path, source_entry_path for the default and development config?

Comment: source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs

Comment: It sounds like you have webpack configured right and files in the right spot. Could you post your `app/javascript/packs/application.js`?

Comment: Which file are you getting an error for? It also looks like you are loading jQuery twice (jQuery and src/jquery.min). If you are not using a gem/npm module for the first jQuery, that looks to be the problem and you can just remove that line. You will want to move the jQuery.min before bootstrap also.

Comment: Are you getting an error for the `require('channels')` line? With the application.js file, as you posted it above, can you copy/paste the exact error message you are getting. Also, is this error coming from web packer while running ./bin/webpack-dev-server?

Comment: now it is fixed. i forgot to give path on `resolved_paths` in `webpacker.yml`. now i gave `resolved_paths: ['app/javascript/src']` in `webpacker.yml` and it is working fine. Thank you so much for helping me.